# How do I connect the multiple pages of the website using forward and backward button with the help of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, dom, history

I have 5 html files as well as 5 CSS files and 5 media queries files that are connected with each other. I have completed all my design but I just wanna connect them with the help of 2 buttons using JavaScript I have **next** button as well as **back** button in my design but don't know how to connect all the files with the help of JavaScript I have tried  a lot of solution but nothing is working for me.
Note: I don't just wanna connect them with the help of href links because they can create problems and not working properly sometimes. Please guide me the solution with the code.
Please if someone can solve my issue or help me in this regard how to get rid of the problem. The[This is my final complete design but I want to connect all the other pages with the help of back and next button but nothing is working for me at that time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3vGQ.png) screen short of my design is attached with the question will someone please guide me in this regard

I am trying to connect all the pages with the help of JavaScript using **next** and **back** button. I am expecting if I click the **next** button next page appear and if I click the **back** button previous page appear but don't know how to do that I have tried a lot of solutions but nothing is working for me

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: I have try the history but simply history Api  is not working for me because i have a lot of files I mean 15 pages including html, CSS and media queries